# Visual Studio 2022 can not automatically detect System.Web.UI.UserControl

Tags: c#, webforms, user-controls, visual-studio-2022

I'm creating a new User Control. In the .cs code-behind `System.Web.UI.UserControl` does not highlight and I cannot use any project from the current Solution. It doesn't show any errors about reference. But when I close the Solution and open it again, it works normal.

When I create the new User Control I see this:
`System.Web.UI.UserControl` not highlights and VS don't show error

[image]

Then I close solution, open it again, and it works as normal:  `System.Web.UI.UserControl` now highlights. And VS auto show error for reference to other project

[image]

I'm using .Net 4.5.2 and code by Visual Studio 2022.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you not enabled the newer forms designer.

tools->options->Web forms designer:

[image]

also, check Web live preview, and turn that off.

Also, you don't mention if you building as "any" cpu, x64, or x32.

Try this:

flip project to x32. Do a re-build all. If that builds, then try see if the UC can work.

If not, then flip project back to x64, and again do a re-build all. This "flip" back, re-build, and then flip back to x64 often works.

And I suppose for good measure, you could try "any" CPU.

You find that this "flip" often lets you work. But, once you do a re-build all, and run? You often then faced with having to do the above flip again.

Comment: Thank to you a lot for your guide but I do step by step like you show but not working. I try on another computer but the same with this Solution, I think my Solution is broken in somewhere, other my Solution working normal

Comment: yes, I have this occurring "only" with some solutions. In the vb.net one, I did a re-build all as x32, and that let me work with the UC, and then I would/could rebuild all as x64 when not waking on pages with the UC. So, don't just do a build, but make sure you using the re-build all for this.  the re-build all with x32 did seem to work for me until I f5 to run, and then often I had to flip again.  As noted, make sure live preview is turned off, and the legacy web form setting in my screen cap is being used.

Comment: In my case, I only close Solution then open again, everything working fine. If you have same my problem, you can try close then open Solution again. My problem only in case create new User Control first time.